# Complex Json type Querying

Tags: c#, json, linq

I get the JSON from another external vendor and I have simplyfied the same here.

Problem : I am searching for instrumentIdentifier in Holding in the json, have to extract it , it can appear at level 2 or level 3 or level 4 in the assetcategory.

I am not sure how to search it properly using linq or normal C# methods, I don't have latest newtonsoft to query based on JsonPath.
Stuck badly using Linq or even normal method,

.net version is 4.0 , newtonsoft 4.5

Comment: can you show some example data of instrumentIdentifier with the structure?

Comment: If you don't have the latest Json.Net, what version DO you have?  Is there a reason you cannot upgrade?  Also what version of the .NET framework do you have available to you?

Comment: Do you want to do the queries on the JSON, or do you want to do the queries on your deserialized classes?

Comment: right now I have handled in a way, in the string querying the instrument identifier extracting only the json, I needed , handling it, it is dirtiest old trick.I want to query using deserialized class.

Comment: Your JSON is broken.  Might you please edit your question and include JSON that passes validation at http://jsonlint.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
public holdings FindHoldings(portfolio portfolio, string instrumentId) 
{
    return FindHoldingsRecursive(portfolio.assetTypes, instrumentId);
}

public holdings FindHoldingsRecursive(
    IEnumerable<subAssetType> assetTypes,
    string instrumentId)
{
    if (assetTypes == null)
        return null;

    return assetTypes
      .Select(a => FindHoldingsRecursive(a, instrumentId))
      .FirstOrDefault(h => h != null);
}

public holdings FindHoldingsRecursive(
    subAssetType assetType, 
    string instrumentId)
{
    return 
        assetType.holdings.FirstOrDefault(h => h.instrumentIdentifier == instrumentId);
        ?? FindHoldingsRecursive(assetType.assetTypes, instrumentId);
}
```

This will do a depth-first search.

If you want a more generic solution to traversing a tree structure, I'd created these extension method for my own benefit:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return collection ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Recurse<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
    {
        return collection.SelectMany(i => i.Recurse(childrenSelector));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Recurse<T>(
        this T parent, 
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
    {
        yield return parent;
        var children = childrenSelector(parent).OrEmpty();
        foreach (var descendant in children.Recurse(childrenSelector))
        {
            yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

This will let you do this:

```
var theHolding = portfolio.assetTypes
    .Recurse(a => a.assetTypes)
    .SelectMany(a => a.holdings.OrEmpty())
    .FirstOrDefault(h => h.instrumentIdentifier == "foo");
```

Comment: In your second `Recurse<T>` extension method, what does `childExpr` refer to?

Comment: Also, in your usage example shouldn't that be `.SelectMany(a => a.holdings.OrEmpty())` instead of `.Select(a => a.holdings)`?

Comment: Ah, yes. Didn't realize `holdings` was a collection. Updating, thanks.

Comment: @RobertAshok - You can accept it an answer if that helped you. Check this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work